# Migrating Large MySQL DB without required storage space

Tags: linux, mysql, migration, data-migration

I have inherited a MySQL DB that takes 220 GB of storage. The machine that it's on is 255 GB, leaving 35 GB free. We are in the process of rewriting the application and will be refactoring the DB as well. We would like to take dumps of the data to move them to a newer/larger DB but we're not sure the best way to do it is, considering we can't increase space nor can we attach additional storage. What is the best way to migrate this data?

Thank you,

Comment: By "to move them to a newer/larger/ DB" does this mean you are migrating the data to a new server? Or are you using the same hardware for the re-written application?

Comment: How do you normally access this database? It seems unlikely that there is no network access to the machine.

Comment: Why can't you get a USB hdd, format it mount it, and copy the data over?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make myself clear. The original machine is at a host that is behind a VPN.  We don't have physical access to the machine.

Answer (score 0):

You need network connectivity on both computers.

On new server:

```
mkdir /old server/
mysqldump -h <old server ip or dns> -c <database name> >/old server/database.sql
```

For example:

```
mysqldump -h 192.168.1.2 -c server /old sever/server.sql
```

On the new server the database can be imported.  You may have to pre-create a blank database of that database name first.

```
mysql -u root -ppassword server  <server.sql
```